# How does Excel show data from other excel workbooks to which I dont have access?

Tags: excel

I got an excel sheet which has a lot of links to other excel sheets.

Now I don't have access to those sheets because they are in someone else's hard drive.

When I open the excel sheet given to me, I get warning that some links could not be updated, which I understand. But the sheet still populates values in cells that are referring to those other excel sheets. How is this possible?

Comment: Because the value is saved when the workbook is saved, presumably by the person who has access to the drive.

Answer (score -1):

It has an embedded copy of the other sheets, which is embedded in the sheet your working on. If the files exists and have been altered, excel updates the existing embedded copies.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that my co worker is getting a #REF error but I am not.